# Commons - Configuration CompositeConfiguration and Preferences

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I am using CompositeConfiguration to read properties from multiple sources (like .propeties files, xml files, System properties etc) as below.

```
ConfigurationFactory factory = new ConfigurationFactory("config.xml");
compConfig = (CompositeConfiguration)factory.getConfiguration();
compConfig.getProperty(propName);
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<properties fileName="Properties1.properties"/>
<properties fileName="Properties2.properties"/>
<properties fileName="Properties3.properties"/>
<system/>
</configuration>
```

In addition to these files, I would like to read Preferences saved in Windows registry as well. I understand that java.util.Preferences API can be used to access values in Windows Registry. I was just wondering if there is a way to read them as well using PropertiesConfiguration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would need to provide your own implementation of the [AbstractConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/AbstractConfiguration.html) class. You could also use the [JNDIConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/JNDIConfiguration.html) class if you're willing to pay for a [JNDI provider for the windows registry](http://www.cogentlogic.com/jndi/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply David. Looks like I have to write my own implementation. Guess I can use this as reference. http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/configuration/branches/configuration2_experimental/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PreferencesConfiguration.java?view=markup